# NODE JS Select SQL Count as total vacio

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, nodejs

Tengo este query, pero no logro alcanzar el **total** que declaro, cada que trato de hacerle un `console.log(unitusedCount[0].total)` me da 0 t algo me dice que es en la forma en la que lo trato de cachar.

```
    router.post('/tc-assign/',async (req,res)=>{
    const {id_user, id_project , id_tc,id_client,amount} = req.body;

    console.log(id_user,id_project,id_tc,id_client,amount);




    const unitusedCount = await pool.query('SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM tc_u where status = 1 and id_client = ?',[id_client]);



    console.log(unitusedCount[0].total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la forma en que capturas el resultado devuelto por la consulta. Además en tu código no veo que uses un bloque `try/catch` para trabajar con las Promesas.

Según la documentación de [`mysql2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper) (asumo que es la librería que consumes), cuando usas una función tipo `async` de envoltorio para trabajar con Promesas, debes capturar los datos de la siguiente forma:

```js
const [rows, fields] = await pool.query('SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM tc_u where status = 1 and id_client = ?',[id_client]);
```

Los nombres de las variables `rows` y `fields` los puedes cambiar a gusto, pero siempre debes capturar 2 valores.

Así, `rows` es un `Array` con el resultado (o resultados) de tu consulta, y `fields` es un `Array` que contiene meta datos relevantes al resultado de la consulta.

Fíjate que en la respuesta de la Promesa no hay un objeto de error, es por ello que debemos usar `try/catch`.

Así tu código podría verse parecido al siguiente:

```js
router.post('/tc-assign/', async (req,res)=>{
  const { id_user, id_project, id_tc, id_client, amount } = req.body;
  console.log(id_user,id_project,id_tc,id_client,amount);
  try {
    const [rows, fields] = await pool.query('SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM tc_u where status = 1 and id_client = ?', [id_client]);
    console.log(rows[0].total); // Una consulta COUNT(*) devuelve sólo una fila en el resultado (por eso usamos rows[0])
    ...
  }
  catch(e) { // <= aquí capturamos un eventual error en la consulta
    console.error(e.message); // mostramos el error
    ...
  }
});
```

Espero que esto aclare las dudas y te ayude a resolver el problema.

**EDICIÓN**

Dado que comentas que usas la librería [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), la cual usa el antiguo sistema de funciones `callback` para manejar los procesos asíncronos, debes crear un envoltorio para tu método `pool.query()`, el cuál devolverá una Promesa que podrás usar en tu código.

En la respuesta a esta pregunta: [Error en almacenar datos con mysql y Node.js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266927/error-en-almacenar-datos-con-mysql-y-node-js/267107#267107), explico básicamente este mismo proceso y además explico cómo hacerlo sin usar Promesas.

Un envoltorio podría ser el siguiente:

```js
const doQuery = (query, params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query(query, params, (error, rows, fields) => {
      if(error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      return resolve([rows, fields]);
    });
  });
}
```

Además debes crear la cadena con la consulta y el `array` de parámetros:

```js
const query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM tc_u where status = 1 and id_client = ?';
const params = [id_client];
```

Luego, escribimos todo esto dentro del método `post` de tu objeto `router`:

```js
router.post('/tc-assign/', async (req,res)=>{
  const { id_user, id_project, id_tc, id_client, amount } = req.body;
  console.log(id_user,id_project,id_tc,id_client,amount);
  // creamos la consulta y los parámetros
  const query = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM tc_u where status = 1 and id_client = ?';
  const params = [id_client];
  // creamos la función envoltorio
  const doQuery = (query, params) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.query(query, params, (error, rows, fields) => {
        if(error) {
          return reject(error);
        }
        return resolve([rows, fields]);
      });
    });
  }
  try {
    // usamos la función envoltorio
    const [rows, fields] = await doQuery(query, params);
    console.log(rows[0].total); // Una consulta COUNT(*) devuelve sólo una fila en el resultado (por eso usamos rows[0])
    ...
  }
  catch(e) { // <= aquí capturamos un eventual error en la consulta
    console.error(e.message); // mostramos el error
    ...
  }
});
```

Con esto ya puedes usar `asyn/await` con la librería `mysql`.

Lo ideal es crear un módulo que puedas importar en cada lugar donde necesites usar el envoltorio, de esta forma no necesitas repetir el código.

Comment: me da 'Cannot read property 'total' of undefined' ya probè con `(fields.total)`

Comment: estoy usando mysql no mysql2

Comment: Entonces no puedes usar promesas a menos que crees tu propia implementación. La librería `mysql` usa el antiguo sistema de `callbacks` y no da soporte para usar `async/await`. En [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266927/error-en-almacenar-datos-con-mysql-y-node-js/267107#267107) respuesta ofrezco una solución, sin embargo editaré esta respuesta para añadir cómo lo debes hacer. Saludos

Comment: acabo de notar que siempre me devuelve 0 , si hago el mismo query en un ui de mysql me da la verdadera suma

Comment: He implementado el código de mi respuesta, uso Express `4.17.1`, Node `12.8.0` y mysql `2.17.1`, mi Servidor MySQL es `14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64)`. El resultado es el esperado al realizar la consulta. Saludos