# Consulto a mi base de datos en mysql desde nodejs, quiero obtener los resultados y guardarlos en una variable pero ¿porque no funciona?

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Este es mi codigo, cuando imprimo en consola muestra []

```js
var results = [];

connection.query("SELECT * FROM employees", (err, rows) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  results = rows;
});    
console.log(results);
```

Comment: Supongo que estas utilizando el paquete `mysql`?

Comment: Si, lo estoy usando

Comment: que deberia hacer para resolver este problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

El problema es de asincronía (y siempre lo es).

El método [.query()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#performing-queries) de la librería [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) tiene las siguientes firmas:

- `query(sqlString, callback)`
- `query(sqlString, values, callback)`
- `query(options, callback)`

En las tres formas vemos que se usa una función [`callback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function). (Relacionado: [*¿Qué es un “callback”?*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/96218/qu%c3%a9-es-un-callback)). Y es que el proceso realizado por el método `query()` es un proceso asíncrono.

Esto significa, que el motor de Javascript hace la llamada del proceso asíncrono y lo envía al [`loop` de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Loop_de_eventos). Cuando el mismo retorne un resultado, se llamará a ejecución a la función pasada como `callback`. Mientras esto sucede, se seguirán ejecutando las tareas que se encuentren después de la llamada al proceso asíncrono.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo que desees hacer con el resultado de la consulta, debes hacerlo dentro de tu función `callback`. Ya que cuando la misma se ejecute el resultado ya estará disponible.

Veamos un ejemplo de lo que ocurre si tratamos de acceder a una variable cuyo valor se asigna dentro de un proceso asíncrono que usa una función `callback`.

```js
let resultado = [];

const miProcesoAsincrono = (str, cb) => {
  console.log(str);
  //simulación de proceso asíncrono con setTimeOut
  setTimeout(() => {
    // se asigna el valor de resultado y se pasa a la función callback
    resultado.push('Algun valor');
    cb(null, resultado);
  }, 0);
}

miProcesoAsincrono('Inicia Proceso Asíncrono', (err, result) => {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('Proceso Asíncrono ha finalizado')
  console.log(result);
});

console.log('Lo siguiente muestra un Array vacío:');
console.log(resultado);
```

Vemos claramente que el resultado se asigna dentro del proceso asíncrono, y el mismo no está disponible inmediatamente, por lo tanto la llamada a `console.log()` que se hace después de llamar al proceso asíncrono devuelve el `array` vacío.

Lo que debes hacer siempre que trabajes con procesos asíncronos, es escribir la lógica de tu programa (que dependa del resultado del proceso asíncrono), dentro de la función que pasas como `callback`:

```js
var results = [];

connection.query("SELECT * FROM employees", (err, rows) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  results = rows;
  // aquí y sólo aquí puedes trabajar con el resultado
  console.log(results);
});
```

Si deseas tener el resultado de tu consulta disponible fuera de la función `callback`, tendrías que usar una función envoltorio que devuelva una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Usar_promesas), dado que la librería `mysql` no trabaja con Promesas directamente. Para eso puedes leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266927/error-en-almacenar-datos-con-mysql-y-node-js/267107#267107), donde explico con detalle la forma de hacerlo.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.

Answer (score -1):

```
 //Esta funcion recibe los datos para acceder a la base de datos
  function getFromDB(mysql, host, database, user, password){

    //Luego devuelve una function que conserva en su entorno lexico los datos para accesar
    // y espera por el query, debe ser asincrona (async)

    return async function(query){

      //En esta variable se almacenara el resultado del query
      let qResult;

      //Crea la conexion
      const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: host,
        database: database,
        user: user,
        password: password,
      })

      //Ejecuta la conexion
      connection.connect(
        error => {
          if(error){
            console.error(`Error connection ${error.stack}`);
            return;
          }
          console.log(`Connected to ${database} as id: ${connection.threadId}`)
        }
        )
        try{
          //podemos usar await ya que estamos dentro de una funcion definida como 
          //asincrona 'async' para esperar el resultado de sendQuery y poder guardarlo
          qResult = await sendQuery(query)

          //Podemos pasarlo a JSON si lo necesitas
          qResult = JSON.stringify(qResult, null, 2)
          
          //esta es la promesa que envuelve el metodo .query()
          //de este modo con el metodo resolve externamos el resultado
          //y es almacenado en la variable qResult; arriba.
          function sendQuery(query) {

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

              connection.query(query, (error, results) => {

                if(error){
                  reject(error)
                }

                resolve(results)

              })
            })
          }
        }catch(error){

          console.error(error)

        }finally{

          connection.end()
        }

        //Arrojamos los resultados para ser almacenados en la constante data
        return qResult
      }
    }
    
    const fromDB = getFromDB(mysql, host, database, user, password)
    
    let query = `SELECT productCode, productURL FROM products;`
    
    const data = fromDB(query)
```